# What the paypal adaptive payments future will be?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

More than a question this is going to be a long story and a call for all those professionals, developers and merchants that are actively using paypal adaptive payments (preapprovals and chained).

I (and my team with me) strongly think that adaptive payments are and have been a great solution.

Since we adopted them in late 2012 we immediately understood the potential and the flexibility of this great set of APIs. The adoption of this APIs in Italy was something like a nightmare in those times. No docs in italian, no support in italian, everything was done in english with one great support person of paypal in Dublin following us in the integration at the phone :) We were pioneers in our country but at the end we finally had our flows done.

Preapprovals + chained payments and the world can be in your hand.

We could do almost anything and this was what we did. A great platform for buying groups that in those last year is expoloding in our country. Today we have dozens of active and happy users (thousands we brought to paypal) and almost one houndred very selected merchants that we've followed step by step with the paypal team in the limit removal nightmare stuff. One, by one.

And here comes the call.
How many are we using them and what will be the future and possible migration solutions?

As almost all of the users of adaptives knows those APIs are well functioning but deprecated since few years. This means that nobody can start new integrations with them but, worst of all, that all those that are actively using them - like us - still don't really know what the future will be. I'm fairly certain that we can't be alone. I'm almost sure that there are other businesses, merchants, developers who have built great ideas relying on those APIs and now that we've given soul and blood for years putting all of our efforts in developing, optimizing, updating and growing our platforms and our communities, we're at a crossroad: to wait and hope or to look for alternatives.

On an app owner view, there's no understandable reason why paypal should shut off those APIs and, infact, till today, fortunately we've heard nothing about a sunsetting of those APIs, however we all know that they have been deprecated and any of us can safely say that there won't be a sunsetting or a forced migration in the future.

So, why don't we start joining our voices to have clear, understandable and certified roadmap and / or plans around this topic?

Talking with the commercial team in Dublin, they say that everything is ok with adaptives and they will continue working for a long time (and this would be great) but, on the other side, talking with the MTS team the view is a little bit different and no so enthusiastic go on mood in the air. Most of all because of the introduction of the PSD2 Directive in Europe.

As many in the European market should have heard, in the last few months another big concern (investing everything in the payments industry) is the PSD2 compliance and maybe just for this directive that the future of adaptives could be involved too.

Adaptives unfortunately are not PSD2 ready and the hope that paypal will put efforts in making them compatible while it is a deprecated solution is very thin.

The strong customer authentication, mandatory in the new rules schema would force the tech team to update all their products but, always on the merchant / app owner / user view, it seems more plausible that paypal will put the more efforts in the new products instead of renewing the old ones.

However, adaptives are both:

- a great solution used by a lot of merchants (again, how much we are?!) in the world continuatively draining new users and merchants (for free) to paypal (just for how the adaptives and preapprovals works, in many cases you're forced to open a paypal account and all we app owners have done this for years);
- an easily adjustable tool to be PSD2 ready

We're now in a "grace period" for PSD2 and that to make Adaptive payments complying with PSD2 directive wouldn't be so hard: preapprovals are the CORE and if you add a strong customer authentication to the preapproval flow the great part of the job is done. Chained payments made direclty at the presence of the user too, just adding a strong customer authentication should fit the needs and server to server chained payments sould fall in the MIT (merchant initiated payments) that seems to be out of the object of the directive.

Forcing migrations, on the other hand, would result in loosing a lot of customers, merchants, app owners that for some reason can't change the architecture because of the specific business model or because they don't find real concrete solutions in alternative APIs. Fixing it appears to be a better solution.

The call to all the adaptive payments users is to join this conversation and bring your thoughts, just to see if we're alone or if we're a lot with the same issue at the door.

An enthusiastic and happy adaptive heavy user and owner in Italy.

Cheers, Fil

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how a platform might change in future, not any actionable details of actually programming against that platform, and therefore is off-topic for SO.

Comment: This is a call placed in a tech community of developers looking for solutions to a (relatively) broad tech issue. The proposal is to collect ideas and suggestions for migrations or alternative solutions. This want to be a gathering informations post with the aim to help all those impacted, really don't think it should be closed if Stack Overflow can be intended as a community too.

Answer (score 1):

In planning for the future, the best approach would likely be to put together a list of your platform's requirements and expected volume, and contact PayPal regarding: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/

You can also look at other options

I don't think anyone knows exactly how long Adaptive Payments will remain available as a legacy service for existing integrations, but I would expect it will be long enough for you to set up a new one that users can migrate to

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Alexander, we've done it but unfortunately without any response. Unfortunately the set of APIs connected to the commerce platform are available only for those (big) businesses followed by a paypal account. We're in the middle, not so small and not yet enough big have access to this. This is one of the reason we're looking both:

a) to an update of adaptives that makes them strong and secure for the years after (SCA ready)
b) or, in alternative, a set of APIs to soft migrations

I think that we are a lot asking for the a) solution paypal might take it in charge.

Comment: My sense is Adaptive APIs are in a legacy/maintenance mode, so I would not expect updates or enhancements. I think the future plan is to expand the commerce platform to more middle-sized enterprises over time.

Comment: Yes Alexander, it is just a little bit more than a hope that they will put efforts in an update. Our concern is that if they will decide to shut down those APIs before expanding the availability of the commerce platform to middle sized enterprises it would result in a disruption for those impacted. In the meantime, there is no guidance from paypal till now so we can wait hoping it will arrive before an eventually disruption (for example with the end of the grace period with the PSD2) or we can think now to alternatives, even outside the paypal environment.